# passing values from popup window to parent window

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, query-string

I have create a page(creation.aspx) with a button. A popup page(pass.aspx) open in a new browser window When i click the button . And some operation made in a popup window and then click submit button in the popup.But i have one doubt. I want to transfer the values from popup window to parent window.

Whether it is possible or not. If it's possible means How?. Please help me to fix this issue.

In parent page:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="img_pass" style="vertical-align:bottom;" runat="server" OnClientClick= "window.open('pass.aspx','','location=0,resizable=0,ScrollBars=1,statusbar=1,width=550,height=550,left=20,top=10,moveable=0') ;return false;" ImageUrl="~/images/bnt_pass.png" Width="20px" Height="20px" />
```

In popup window:

```
Response.Redirect("creation.aspx?id =" + value1.Text + "&" + value.Text);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string redirectUrl = "creation.aspx?id =" + value1.Text + "&" + value.Text;
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Redirect", "window.parent.location = " + redirectUrl , true);
```

Comment: Value not passing to the parent window

Answer (score 0):

Use `Session` variables to pass the value from one page to another.
(ie) Save your required values in `Session[""]` variables in server side events(buttonclick, dropdownchanged etc) in popup page and make use of the `Session[""]` variables in your parent page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following javascript code to return the value to parent window.

function fnOk()
    {

```
    top.returnValue = "Data";
    window.close();
    return true;

}
```